# json - appending URIs to hostnames programatically through jq?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I've been using jq to sort of map multiple json files, i've had good success with jq but blocked on finalizing my end results. long story short.

**I have the following json:
main.json**

```
{
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "org": "Alison Sandbox",
      "physical_endpoint": "https://dev.service-now.com/ESD_Assets.do?SOAP",
      "physical_service": "ServiceNowService_v1_0",
      "virtual_endpoint": "https://sandbox-dv.soa.com:443/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
      "virtual_service": "ServiceNowService_v1_0_vs0",
      "vs_endpoints": [
        "https://sandbox-ci.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv101.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv102.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv103.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv104.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv105.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv107.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv108.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv109.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv110.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv111.soa.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "org": "Architecture Frameworks",
      "physical_endpoint": "http://localhostdayofweek/DayOfWeek",
      "physical_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1001",
      "virtual_endpoint": "https://sandbox-dv.soa.com:443/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
      "virtual_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
      "vs_endpoints": [
        "https://sandbox-ci.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv101.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv102.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv103.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv104.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv105.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv107.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv108.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv109.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv110.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv111.soa.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "org": "Architecture Frameworks",
      "physical_endpoint": "http://localhostdayofweek/DayOfWeek/updated",
      "physical_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1002",
      "virtual_endpoint": "https://sandbox-dv.soa.com:443/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
      "virtual_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0",
      "vs_endpoints": [
        "https://sandbox-ci.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv101.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv102.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv103.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv104.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv105.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv107.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv108.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv109.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv110.soa.com",
        "https://sandbox-dv111.soa.com"
      ]
    },
```

.
.
.
.

**I wanted to append the URI part from virtual_endpoint attribute to each of the vs_endpoints (which i appended through jq from another json file)
My end results would look like this:**

```
{
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "org": "Alison Sandbox",
      "physical_endpoint": "https://dev.service-now.com/ESD_Assets.do?SOAP",
      "physical_service": "ServiceNowService_v1_0",
      "virtual_endpoint": "https://sandbox-dv.soa.com:443/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
      "virtual_service": "ServiceNowService_v1_0_vs0",
      "vs_endpoints": [
        "https://sandbox-ci.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv101.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv102.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv103.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv104.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv105.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv107.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv108.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv109.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv110.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv111.soa.com/ServiceNow/ESD_ServiceNowSvc_v1_0_vs0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "org": "Architecture Frameworks",
      "physical_endpoint": "http://localhostdayofweek/DayOfWeek",
      "physical_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1001",
      "virtual_endpoint": "https://sandbox-dv.soa.com:443/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
      "virtual_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
      "vs_endpoints": [
        "https://sandbox-ci.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv101.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv102.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv103.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv104.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv105.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv107.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv108.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv109.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv110.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0",
        "https://sandbox-dv111.soa.com/testpromotion/DayOfWeekServiceMT1001_vs0"
       ]
    },
    {
       "org": "Architecture Frameworks",
      "physical_endpoint": "http://localhostdayofweek/DayOfWeek/updated",
      "physical_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1002",
      "virtual_endpoint": "https://sandbox-dv.soa.com:443/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
      "virtual_service": "DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0",
      "vs_endpoints": [
        "https://sandbox-ci.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv101.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv102.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv103.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv104.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv105.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv106.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv107.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv108.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv109.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv110.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2",
        "https://sandbox-dv111.soa.com/UPDATE/DayOfWeekServiceMT1002_vs0_2"
      ]
    },
```

.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 1):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq '.endpoints |= map((.virtual_endpoint | sub("https?://[^/]+"; "")) as $end_p 
                      | .vs_endpoints |= [.[] + $end_p] )' main.json
```

Demonstration:
https://jqplay.org/s/ypiYcNBa-I